# Sorting TV Shows (dictionaries and lists)

Tags: python

I am not getting any output from the coding. where am doing wrong?

Write a program that first reads in the name of an input file and then reads the input file using the file.readlines() method. The input file contains an unsorted list of number of seasons followed by the corresponding TV show. Your program should put the contents of the input file into a dictionary where the number of seasons are the keys, and a list of TV shows are the values (since multiple shows could have the same number of seasons).

Sort the dictionary by key (least to greatest) and output the results to a file named output_keys.txt. Separate multiple TV shows associated with the same key with a semicolon (;), ordering by appearance in the input file. Next, sort the dictionary by values (alphabetical order), and output the results to a file named output_titles.txt.

Ex: If the input is:

file1.txt
and the contents of file1.txt are:

```
20
Gunsmoke
30
The Simpsons
10
Will & Grace
14
Dallas
20
Law & Order
12
Murder, She Wrote
```

the file output_keys.txt should contain:

```
10: Will & Grace
12: Murder, She Wrote
14: Dallas
20: Gunsmoke; Law & Order
30: The Simpsons
```

and the file output_titles.txt should contain:

```
Dallas
Gunsmoke
Law & Order
Murder, She Wrote
The Simpsons
Will & Grace
```

Here is the code:

```
def read_file(file1):
    dict1 = {}
    with open(file1, 'r') as f:
        file1 = f.readlines()
        for file in range(0, len(file1)-1, 2):
            if file[i].strip() == '':
                continue
            count = int(file1[file].strip())
            show = file1[file + 1].strip()
            if count in dict1.keys():
                showlist = dict1.get(count)
                showlist.append(show)
            else:
                dict1[count] = [show]
                print(count,show)
    return dict1
    
def output_keys(file1, dict1):
    with open(file1, 'w+') as q:
        for key in sorted(dict1.keys()):
            q.write("{}: {}".format(key, ';'.join(dict1.get(key))))
            print("{}: {}".format(key, ';'.join(dict1.get(key))))
def output_titles(file1, dict1):
    titles = []
    for title in dict1.values():
        titles.extend(title)
    with open(file, 'w+') as o:
        for title in sorted(titles):
            o.write("{}\n".format(title))
            print(title)
def main(file1):
    if dict1 is None:
        print('Error: Invalid file name provided: {}'.format(file1))
        return    
    output_filename1 = 'output_keys.txt'
    output_filename2 = 'output_titles.txt'
    output_keys(dict1, output_filename1)
    output_titles(dict1, output_filename2)
file_name = input()  
main(file_name)
```

Comment: Is it crashing with an error? And what is the point of the main function? Double check your indentation levels

Comment: You seem to have a typo in `read_file` on the line ` for i in range(0, len(file1)-1, 2):`, where you probably want `file` (which is the contents of the file) rather than `file1` (which is the string with the name of the file). Using more distinct variable names would help you there (e.g. `file_name` vs `file_contents`). There are several other similar typos in the function as you refer to your dictionary variously as `dict_1`, `dict1` and `dic1`. Reading further, I see lots more errors, perhaps two many for us to help with. You should probably troubleshoot each of your functions separately.

Comment: @Blckknght edited them but it's still not working... I have been sitting with this lab for hours but can't figure out why it is not giving me any output. this is what i am getting-Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 40, in <module>
    main(file_name)
  File "main.py", line 32, in main
    if dict1 is None:
NameError: name 'dict1' is not defined

Comment: You are never calling `read_file`, you just start trying to use a dictionary name `dict1` that doesn't exist as far as I can see. Depending on how you're running this code, that should give you an error or something (you might want to investigate why you're not getting any error messages or debugging is going to be a nightmare). Other issues I see is that you're calling our `output_X` functions with the arguments in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your above code. It is throwing an error. When you say there is no output, do you mean the terminal just hangs? If so it's because it is waiting for you to enter the file name.

I added some print statements to a portion of your code. Use the print statement generously when debugging your programs. I put a number on the printed string in the order I would expect the program to print

```
def main(file1):
    print('3: main is called. referencing dict1')
    if dict1 is None:
        print('Error: Invalid file name provided: {}'.format(file1))
        return 
    
    print('4: success -> dict1 exists')
       
    output_filename1 = 'output_keys.txt'
    output_filename2 = 'output_titles.txt'
    output_keys(dict1, output_filename1)
    output_titles(dict1, output_filename2)

# 1 - get filename from user 
print('1: asking user for input')
file_name = input() # <- program waits for you to enter file1.txt

print(f'2: input recieved: {file_name}')  
main(file_name)
```

That should help you diagnose what's wrong. I'm also adding a slight refactor. In general, you accept arguments from the `main` function through the command line. That's not a set-in-stone rule or anything, but when you're starting out you can think of `main` as the entry to your program.

I didn't check `read_file`, `output_keys` or `output_names`, so if you have errors in them just follow your program line by line and add print statements of where you think the program should execute, and if the variables are what you would expect them to be.

```
def main():
    print('enter file name: ')
    file1 = input()

    dict1 = read_file(file1)
    if dict1 is None:
        print('Error: Invalid file name provided: {}'.format(file1))
        return    
    output_filename1 = 'output_keys.txt'
    output_filename2 = 'output_titles.txt'
    output_keys(dict1, output_filename1)
    output_titles(dict1, output_filename2)
    
# Add the following - it's what starts your program.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```